# Using the Cauchy integral to construct holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I was going through David C. Ullrich's wonderful text *Complex Made Simple*, when I came to Theorem 10.3.1. The Theorem states

> If $f\in C(\partial\mathbb{D})$ then $C[f]\in H(\mathbb{D})$,

where $\mathbb{D}$ is the open unit disk, $C(\partial\mathbb{D})$ and $H(\partial\mathbb{D})$ are the spaces of continuous and holomorphic functions, respectively, on $\partial\mathbb{D}$, and
$C[f]$ is the Cauchy integral: $$C[f](z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial\mathbb{D}}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}\,dw.$$

I'm sure I'm misunderstanding trivial here, but when I plug in $f(z)=1/z$, I get
$$
C[1/z](z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial\mathbb{D}}\frac{1/w}{w-z}\,dw=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{e^{it}-z}\,dt=-\frac{1}{z}.
$$
But I don't understand; $-1/z$ has pole at $z=0$. Is the theorem implying holomorphicity in some extended sense where $\infty$ is allowed? Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are mixing up $w$ and $z$ in your last equation. I see an integral in $dz$ equal to a function of $z$: there is something wrong.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Oh wow you're right. I knew it was something trivial. I want to delete this now out of embarresment.

Comment: I have asked several "embarrassing" questions myself and I don't think one should be ashamed. Moreover, it is interesting to see the result of the computation: what is $C[\frac{1}{w}](z)$?

Comment: Are you sure? I would expect $C[f](z)$ to be equal to $f$ on the boundary of the disk, for any $f\in C(\partial \mathbb{D})$. The function $f(w)=\frac{1}{w}$ is singular at $w=0$ but it is continuous on $\partial \mathbb{D}$. There must be something wrong.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yes there was. In "correcting" my mistake, I actually created a new one. The original mistake you caught was (I believe) a typo on my part -- I had originally meant to put $dw$.

But now I don't see the error in my original computation anymore.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro It's an exceptional situation when $f$ coincides with the boundary values of its Cauchy integral. The boundary values of holomorphic functions are very restricted (unlike e.g. boundary values of harmonic functions). You must have $$\int_{\partial \mathbb{D}} z^k\cdot f(z)\,dz = 0$$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ for $f$ being the boundary values of a holomorphic function on the disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have miscomputed the integral. Doing a partial fraction decomposition, we find

$$\frac{1/w}{w-z} = \frac{1}{z}\biggl(\frac{1}{w-z} - \frac{1}{w}\biggr),$$

and so the residue theorem tells us

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\partial \mathbb{D}} \frac{1/w}{w-z}\,dw = \begin{cases} 0 &, \lvert z\rvert < 1 \\ -\frac{1}{z} &, \lvert z\rvert > 1.\end{cases}$$

For $\lvert z\rvert < 1$, the residues of the integrand at $0$ and at $z$ cancel.

Comment: I wish I would have thought to use the residue theorem. Thank you!

Comment: I find this result very interesting and surprising. I was sure that, on $\partial \mathbb{D}$, one should have found $\frac{1}{z}$. But your previous comment is perfectly clear. (I have learned something from this discussion, thank you very much).

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Does this prove that there exists no holomorphic function  on $\mathbb{D}$ having values $1/z$ on $\partial\mathbb{D}$?

Comment: Yes. Actually, this is proven quickly with the idea suggested by Daniel Fischer's comment. Suppose by contradiction that a function $f$, holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$ and such that $f(w)=\frac1w$ on $\partial \mathbb D$ exists. Then by Cauchy's formula one should have $\int_{\partial \mathbb D} f\, dw =0.$ But the direct computation with the residue theorem gives $\int_{\partial \mathbb D} f\, dw = 2\pi i$.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to see it:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{e^{it}-z}\,dt = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{e^{-it}}{1-ze^{-it}}\,dt = \int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-it}(1+ze^{-it} +z^2e^{-2it} + \cdots )\,dt$$ $$ = \int_{0}^{2\pi}(e^{-it}+ze^{-2it} +z^2e^{-3it} + \cdots )\,dt.$$

Switch the order of integration and summation and you have a sum of $0$'s.